# Visual Studio 2013 Automatically Inserting Closing Tags

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studios 2013 and I have tried multiple solutions I have found online and nothing is working.  This seems like it would be a simple thing to change, but when I create a tag, it automatically adds the closing tag.  I would rather type out my tags myself, because sometimes I am changing a tag and then I have to either drag or cut and paste it to where it actually needs to be.  It is frustrating.

Comment: have you looked in the Options? tools-options-environment-brace completion then make sure it is unchecked!

Comment: I have checked and tried a lot of different options.  I don't see the specific path you are talking about.  Under tools-options-text editor-all languages though I see automatic brace completion, but it isn't checked.  It has like a box in it instead and I have tried to click it and it doesn't save it.  I uncheck and click Ok and when I go back, it is still selected.

Comment: This works on Visual Studio 2015 as well, the [visual-studio] tag may be more fitting for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Advanced -> then change Auto insert close tag to false and save.

Here's a screenshot of the settings:

[Options Screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9TM5a38hdbndDZYNThOa3E2bWs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You may also need to uncheck the "Auto insert close tag" under HTML (Web Forms) -> Formatting, even if you are working in ASP.NET MVC, not Web Forms.

Comment: Thanks, @SamMagura, I had to do this for my MVC project in VS 2017,  even though there are no WebForms and it's a Razor document.

Comment: [Here's the screenshot nweg posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MUxl.png) backed up to stack.imgur.com (in case the link goes bad). It's recommended that you use stack.imgur.com for all images posted to Stack Overflow.